# Quick book payment integration issue

Tags: php, quickbooks

I need to integrate quickbook payment in my site with PHP, But I face an error given below:

> Fatal error: Uncaught QuickBooksOnline\API\Exception\ServiceException:
>   Http Status Code [403]: Request is not made successful. Response
>   Code:[403] with body: [  
>    message=AuthorizationFailed;
>   errorCode=003100; statusCode=403 The access token
>   does not have sufficient scope  
>    ]. thrown in
>   /home/treasu46/public_html/qb/qb/payment_int/vendor/quickbooks/v3-php-sdk/src/Core/HttpClients/SyncRestHandler.php
>   on line 226

```
    <?php
require "../vendor/autoload.php";

use QuickBooksOnline\API\DataService\DataService;
use QuickBooksOnline\API\Core\Http\Serialization\XmlObjectSerializer;
use QuickBooksOnline\API\Facades\Invoice;
// Prep Data Services
$dataService = DataService::Configure(array(
    'auth_mode' => 'oauth2',
    'ClientID' => "xxxxxxxxxx",
    'ClientSecret' => "xxxxxxxxx",
    'accessTokenKey' =>'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'refreshTokenKey' => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    'QBORealmID' => "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    'baseUrl' => "Development"
));
$dataService->setLogLocation("/Users/hlu2/Desktop/newFolderForLog");
$dataService->throwExceptionOnError(true);
//Add a new Invoice
$theResourceObj = Invoice::create([
    "Line" => [
    [
         "Amount" => 100.00,
         "DetailType" => "SalesItemLineDetail",
         "SalesItemLineDetail" => [
           "ItemRef" => [
             "value" => 20,
             "name" => "Hours"
           ]
         ]
    ]
    ],
    "CustomerRef"=> [
          "value"=> 1
    ],
    "BillEmail" => [
          "Address" => "Familiystore@intuit.com"
    ],
    "BillEmailCc" => [
          "Address" => "a@intuit.com"
    ],
    "BillEmailBcc" => [
          "Address" => "v@intuit.com"
    ]
]);
$resultingObj = $dataService->Add($theResourceObj);
$error = $dataService->getLastError();
if ($error) {
    echo "The Status code is: " . $error->getHttpStatusCode() . "\n";
    echo "The Helper message is: " . $error->getOAuthHelperError() . "\n";
    echo "The Response message is: " . $error->getResponseBody() . "\n";
}
else {
    echo "Created Id={$resultingObj->Id}. Reconstructed response body:\n\n";
    $xmlBody = XmlObjectSerializer::getPostXmlFromArbitraryEntity($resultingObj, $urlResource);
    echo $xmlBody . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Provide some codes that you have did.

Comment: I update my question with code. Kindly check it and guide me.

Comment: Can you clarify - are you trying to use the QuickBooks PAYMENTS API, or the QuickBooks ONLINE API?

 

You say you're trying to use the Payments one, but you're hitting an Online endpoint.

 

What did you set your scopes to in your application? Did you include both QuickBooks Online and QuickBooks Payments?

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr. Thank you for your reply.
actually, I am new in Quickbook. my client wants to integrate a payment gateway with QuickBooks and I have no idea how to integrate this payment gateway. I find this example from Google and try to make payment. but I still facing issues if possible please help me how to integrate Quickbooks payment gateway in my website.

Comment: Now I'm even more confused. You're trying to integrate a payment gateway with QuickBooks? Specifically what payment gateway? That isn't even possible... is it QuickBooks Payments, or some other gateway?

Comment: QuickBooks Payments.